# I need a popover in my modal with bootstrap 3.0.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi my problem isthat the popover that shoud be in the model when toggled, are instead directing to the body behind the modal in the top left corner and not shown in the modal.

here is my index code:

```
<button type="button" id="example" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" 
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" 
data-content="And here's some amazing     content" 
data-original-title="Hej" >
<img/>
</button>
```

The knouckoutbootstrap.js lookes like this:

```
$(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).removeData("modal").modal();
        }
        else {
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
};
$('#example').popover();
var lockerLoanViewModel = new LockerLoanViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(lockerLoanViewModel);
lockerLoanViewModel.initializeViewModel();
});
```

I don't know if its helpfull but here is the stylesheet:

```
body {
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.gridContainer {
margin-top: 30px;
}
.popover {
z-index: 1060;
position: fixed;
display:inherit;
}
```

If you wanna ask me something pls do i really need help with this. (sorry for bad english :D )

Comment: What is the z-index of the modal it is disapearing behind?

Comment: the z-index of the modal are 1040 9 i have tryid doing it with z-index 9999 too and nothing are different

Comment: Note that z-index is relative. Is the modal embedded in another element with a z-index?

Comment: no its not embedded in another element. mabye if the bootstrap does it.

Comment: Maybe you could create an example on jsfiddle? That would help us helping you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks every one i fixed it my self the solution was that i changed the script to

```
$(function () {
$('.openModal').on('click', function (e) {
$('#editLockerModal')
    .modal({
    backdrop 'static',
    keyboard false
});

$('#example').popover();
});
var lockerLoanViewModel = new LockerLoanViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(lockerLoanViewModel);
lockerLoanViewModel.initializeViewModel();
});
```